# SFML. Изменение размера камеры в соответствии с расстоянием между игроками

Tags: c++, sfml

Всем привет! Такой вопрос. Пишу игру на SFML. Есть два игрока. Нужно реализовать увеличение или уменьшение области видимости камеры так, чтобы были видны оба игрока, при этом, сохранив пропорции соотношения сторон. Как это реализовать? В гугле ничего подходящего не нашел.

Comment: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1View.php

Comment: Я все это просмотрел, перед тем как написать сюда. Укажите мне на конкретную функцию, если я что-то упустил.

Comment: @ДаниилСкотников ну так делаете нужный `sf::View`, а затем цепляете его к `sf::RenderTarget` (например, к `sf::RenderWindow`) с помощью `sf::RenderTarget::setView`

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужный мне **View** меняется в зависимости от расстояния между объектами.

Comment: А в чем собственно затруднение менять View?

Comment: Когда меняешь соотношение ширины и высоты, в соответствии в расстоянием между объектами, во View, картинка искажается.

Comment: Ну тогда не меняйте соотношение сторон.